# Finding general term for a sequence satisyfing provided conditions (with goniometric functions)

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I want to inquire about how would one find the formula for $a_n$ (or reccurently) if we know:

1. $$ \alpha_k = arctan\left(\frac{a_{(n+1)}}{a_n} \right) $$
2. $$ \sin{\alpha_k} = \sin{\alpha_{(k-1)}} \cdot \frac{ a_n }{a_{(n+1)}}  $$

This is also true for the first elements, the sequence entry condition is

$$ \alpha_1 = \arctan{ \left( \frac{a_2}{a_1} \right)}$$
It does not matter what exact values $a_1 $ and $a_2$ hold as long as they satisfy this condition 
When I try to plug in those conditions together, I get $ a_{(n+1)} = a_{(n+1)} $ which is obviously true but also not helpful at all.

Comment: Are the two indices $k$ and $n$ related to each other ? Shouldn't they be same ?

Comment: There is a constant solution given by $a_{k} = \tfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: The $a$ and $\alpha$ are similar enough that it is easy to misunderstand what you wrote. Please use more distinct names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me for changing $a_n$ to $a_i$. Maybe managed to solve it.
\begin{gather*}
\sin{\theta_i} a_i = \sin{\theta_{(i-1)}} a_{(i-1)} \
\sin{\theta_i} = \sin{\theta_{(i-1)}} \cdot \frac{ a_{(i-1)} }{a_{(i)}} \\
\end{gather*}
Now we would like to express $\sin{\theta}$
\begin{gather*}
\tan \theta_i = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{ a_{(i+1)} }{a_i} \
\sin \theta_i = \frac{ a_{(i+1)} }{a_i} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \left( \frac{ a_{(i+1)} }{a_i} \right)^2}}
\end{gather*}
And now we substitute this into the previous equation
\begin{gather*}
\frac{ a_{(i+1)} }{n_i} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \left( \frac{ a_{(i+1)} }{a_i} \right)^2}} = \frac{ a_i }{n_{(i-1)}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \left( \frac{ a_i}{a_{(i-1)}} \right)^2}} \cdot \frac{ a_{(i-1)} }{a_{i}} \\
a_{(i+1)}^2 = a_{(i-1)}^2 \\
\end{gather*}

Thus, the initial condition $\theta$ should hold, along with the following recursion formula. I have no idea whether my solution is correct and I'll mark the the anwsers accordingly when I get the results.
\begin{gather*}
\tan{\theta} = \frac{a_2}{a_1} \\
n_{(i+1)} = \begin{cases}
+ a_{(i-1)} \\
- a_{(i-1)}
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there are explicit closed forms for $a_k$ and $\alpha_k$, but you can find recursive formulas. The two relations combine as follows :
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\sin\alpha_{n-1}}{\sin\alpha_n} = \tan\alpha_n,
$$
hence
$$
\sin\alpha_{n-1}\cos\alpha_n = \sin^2\alpha_n = 1 - \cos^2\alpha_n,
$$
which is a quadratic equation for $\cos\alpha_n$, solved by
$$
\alpha_n^\pm = \arccos\left(\frac{-\sin\alpha_{n-1} \pm \sqrt{4 + \sin^2\alpha_{n-1}}}{2}\right).
$$
Once you have computed the values of $\alpha_n$ recursively until a given step, you can calculate $a_n$ with the following recursion :
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n\tan\alpha_n = a_1 \prod_{k=1}^n \tan\alpha_k
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I've tried to solve this and came up with another solution which I expect to be wrong. I have to post it as an answer because of the character limit.